# Cannot get content of iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am loading a local html document in an iframe, then trying to get access to its document from a script.

This is the javascript:

```
let ifrm = document.getElementById('iframeid');
console.log(ifrm);
let doc = ifrm.contentWindow.document;
console.log(doc);
```

This is the declaration of my iframe:

```
<iframe src="untitled.html" style="display:none" id="iframeid"></iframe>
```

This is the result:
[image: The content of head and body gets lost.]

As you can see, the content of the iframe disappears when I try to get the document. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code is not showing any specific content that you say you are trying to get. Are you trying to get `div.content`? Also the dev tools display the document of the ifrane as well as it's contents. Nothing has disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, you have to wait for the `onload` event.

Take a look here: http://plnkr.co/edit/fNEZLyWkjT952a7e3WNy?p=preview